# EditText not updating with soft keyboard on QVGA devices

Tags: android, android-edittext

I'm having a problem with an EditText (only on QVGA devices, I've tested it on the QVGA emulator and on a Samsung i5500).

When the user clicks on the EditText and the soft keyboard comes up, only the first letter that the user enters appears on the field. The others only show up when the user closes the keyboard or some other event happens.

I don't know if this is a bug (it works on the higher res emulator), but is there any workaround I can use to give a better experience to my users right now?

My (messy) code is here:
https://github.com/bani/SMS-Denuncia/tree/master/android/

And the EditText I'm having a problem with is at
https://github.com/bani/SMS-Denuncia/blob/master/android/res/layout/local.xml

```
<EditText android:id="@+id/vagao2"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:maxLength="12"
android:textSize="18sp"
android:text=""
android:imeOptions="actionSend"
android:visibility="invisible" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Somehow it got fixed when I surrounded my layout with ScrollView.